# WPF styling dynamically added GridView columns based on value

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF, and have the following problem:

I have a ListView presented as grid. The columns of the grid are added dynamically from code behind (myDataGrid is the GridView inside myListView):

```
myListView.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;

foreach (var col in myDataTable.Columns) {
    var column = new GridViewColumn();
    column.Header = col.ColumnName;
    column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(col.ColumnName);                    
    myDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

This works fine, i'm only having touble styling it.
So how can I add a custom styling to these columns based on their values?
For example, I would like that every cell that has the "0" in it to have yellow background.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you need, but should help for sure:
http://highfieldtales.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/hacking-the-wpf-gridview-final-revised-release/